# Azure Cosmos DB - any downside of using very low TTL for health check items?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

As part of the health checks that we have implemented for an app, we are attempting to write a dummy document to the database. For this document, we are using a TTL (time-to-live) of 10 seconds, so that Cosmos DB automatically cleans up the document.

My question is: Is there a downside (performance, RU cost, etc.) of setting the TTL all the way down to 1 second? As soon as the document was successfully written, the health check is happy and we don't care about the document anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no downside, performance degredation or extra cost assocuiated to the setting of low TTL.
If you look at this documentation [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/time-to-live). It states.

> Deletion of expired items is a background task that consumes left-over
> Request Units, that is Request Units that haven't been consumed by
> user requests. Even after the TTL has expired, if the container is
> overloaded with requests and if there aren't enough RU's available,
> the data deletion is delayed. Data is deleted once there are enough
> RUs available to perform the delete operation. Though the data
> deletion is delayed, data is not returned by any queries (by any API)
> after the TTL has expired.